# Show that the power set of $\Omega = \Bbb N$ is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\Omega = \Bbb N$ and $P(\Omega)$ be the power set of $\Omega$. Show that the power set does indeed possess the properties of a $\sigma$-algebra.

Now, this seems a little bit trivial to me, but that's why I'm actually "afraid" that I might have done something wrong.

$\emptyset, \Omega \in P(\Omega):$

This follows directly from the definition of a power set.

$A \in P(\Omega) \Rightarrow A^c \in P(\Omega):$

For $A \subset \Omega$, we get that $A^c = \Omega \setminus A \subset \Omega $ since $A^c$ only contains natural numbers. This is obviously equivalent to the statement above.

$A_1, A_2,  \ ... \in P(\Omega) \Rightarrow \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k = A \in P(\Omega):$

For $A_1, A_2,  \ ...  \subset \Omega$, it is $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k = A \subset \Omega$ since it obviously only contains natural numbers. This is, once again, equivalent to the statement above.

Comment: I thin it is perfect

Comment: It is so trivial that I would write down: it is trivial!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too, but it was mentioned that it has to be explained in detail. Don't know why though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The power set of any set $M$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra (nearly) by definition: It contains all subsets of $M$. Depending on your definition of union, intersection and complement you will see that they all are of the form

$$ \{ \color{#c00000}{x \in M}: \text{some condition on x}  \}.
$$

So any union, intersection or complement is by definition an element of the power set of $M$ - simply because they are subsets of $M$.