# Proof verification: Closed under countable union

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\Omega$ be countable. Let $\{A_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable collection of subsets of $\Omega$. Want to show $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \subseteq \Omega$.

I just want to check the soundness of my argument below: If $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n $, then $\exists$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in A_n$. But since $A_n \subseteq \Omega$, we have that $x \in \Omega$. Hence, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \subseteq \Omega$.

[Similar Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003346/show-that-the-power-set-of-omega-bbb-n-is-indeed-a-sigma-algebra)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct, although it's worth noting that you didn't use "countable" anywhere. You can be a bit more streamlined by dropping that condition:

> **Theorem:** Let $\Omega$ be a set a $\mathscr U$ be a set of subsets of $\Omega$. Then $\bigcup \mathscr U \subseteq \Omega$.
>
> **Proof:** Suppose that $x\in \bigcup \mathscr U$. Then, there is some $U\in\mathscr U$ such that $x\in U$. Since $U\subseteq \Omega$ we have $x\in \Omega$. As $x$ was arbitrary, this implies $\bigcup \mathscr U \subseteq \Omega$.

This is pretty much what you wrote verbatim without an indexing set - I'm not suggesting it's any better as a proof (yours is essentially without fault), but it's worth noting when things work in more generality.